# Show the "Firstname" & "Lastname" after submit form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have been searching for a long time but i cannot find it, so i hope that someone can help me out with my issue.

So i have a HTML form with some input fields like:
Firstname - Lastname - E-mailadres - Telephone
And a button with for sending the form.

Right now the form does 2 things after submit :

1. It will send me a email with the filled details
2. It save the filled details in a Database with a ID number for each person.

I just have a simple send.php as form action.

So if someone will press the Send Button, they will see the page: send.php

When they press the button: They will see: Hi, Thank you very much! We will contact you.

But i want too show the FirstName they filled in the form on the send.php succes page.

**So example:** if they type in the input field firstname: **Antony**
and in the lastname: **Qui**

And when they press send, they will see: Hi **Antony Qui**, Thank you very much! We will contact you.

I hope that someon can help me out with this

Thank you very much!

This is the html form code:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname">
            </div>


            <div>
                <label for="name">Lastname</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname">
            </div>
 </form>
```

And this is the send.php code : **http://justpaste.it/sendphpcode**

I'm sorrry i could not paste the code here...

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" before you post your next question.

Comment: Include your code snippet in your post buddy.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We'd love to help you, and some sample code and a more clearly phrased question can point us in the right direction!

Comment: @DesignStudios just the relevant code which you think is causing the problem would be enough for us to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL/DR**

This is a brief overview of how it'd be done.

---

I assume you already have a form that is being sent via `POST`..?

```
<form action="yourpage.php" method="post">
....
</form>
```

In your form, you'll have `<input>`'s, to access these, they'll need `name` attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
.....
```

To access the posted variables in PHP, you need to check the `$_POST` super global.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

And if your user has filled out their form correctly and you've set it up correctly, you'll see something like this:

```
Array(
    [firstname] => User_Input,
    [lastname] => User_Input
)
```

Allowing you to access them as you please:

```
echo "Hi {$_POST['firstname']} {$_POST['lastname']}";
```

---

**Notes**

Make sure you check to ensure that the user input is set (meaning they actually submitted a firstname/lastname), by using [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) and/or [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset):

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
    echo 'First Name is: '. $_POST['firstname'];
}
```

Since it seems that you would require both the `firstname` **and** the `lastname`, I would run it through this:

```
$required = array('firstname', 'lastname');
$missing = array();
foreach($required as $find) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$find]) || empty($_POST[$find])) {
        $missing[] = $find;
    }
}

if(!empty($missing)) {
    echo "Please supply the missing fields: " . implode(", ", $missing);
} else {
    echo "Hi {$_POST['firstname']} {$_POST['lastname']}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had too put this : <?php echo "Hi {$_POST['firstname']} {$_POST['lastname']}"; ?> in my send.php file . And it works now!